# play 2.0 nest scala expression of reusable template block not interpreted

Tags: playframework-2.0

```
@menu = @{
    <div class="subnav subnav-fixed">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">User<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="@{controllers.user.routes.Admin.list(1)}">all</a></li>
                <li><a href="@{controllers.user.routes.Admin.insert()}">create</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 }
```

I define a function like that.

> But the @{controllers.user.routes.Admin.list(1)} expression not interpreted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For info, the second '@' of the first line can be removed:

```
@menu = {
...
}
```

Then, the '{' and '}' can be omitted too:

```
<li><a href="@controllers.user.routes.Admin.list(1)">all</a></li>
```